# How to add a secondary menu to Bolt CMS?

Tags: php, html, twig, bolt-cms

The default way to add a menu to a template::

```
{{ menu(identifier = 'footer',
        template = 'partials/_sub_menu.twig',
        params = {'withsubmenus': false, 'class': 'inline-list align-right'}**strong text**
) }}
```

But how to build a secondary menu from other files than `menu.yml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a secondary menu go to `menu.yml` add for the mentioned example this lines of code:

```
footer:
    - label: Imprint
      title: Go to Imprint
      path: page/imprint
      class: first
```

The documentation can be found here: https://docs.bolt.cm/3.0/content/menus

> **Further explanation:**

1. All menus used have to be declared in `menu.yml`.
2. To render them correctly you can call them in two different ways.

**Example #1:**

```
{{ menu(identifier = 'footer', template = 'partials/_sub_menu.twig') }}
```

**Example #2 (Short hand syntax):**

```
{{ menu(footer', 'partials/_sub_menu.twig') }}
```

> Note: You can define more than one menu in your menu.yml file, but you
>   should define only one menu in each template file. So, if you have
>   multiple menus that should be rendered with different HTML, you should
>   have as many _menu_menuname.twig files in your theme.